# Assign user to tasks automatically (Viewflow, Django)

Tags: python, django, django-viewflow

I'm using [Viewflow](http://viewflow.io)/Django and trying to assign tasks created by dynamic nodes.

I'm using the same `nodes.py` in [customnode](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/tree/master/demo/customnode).

However, I need to automatically assign each new task based on information in the `MOCTask model` (the assignee).

But tasks don't allow an Assign with anything other than a specific user object and I don't have access to the `MOCTask` objects (they are related by foreign key to MOC, which is related by foreign key to `MOCProcess`, the flow itself).

My code I was trying (flows.py):

```
...
split_on_task_assignment = (
  DynamicSplit(lambda p: MOCTask.objects.filter(MOC=p.MOC).count())
  .IfNone(this.end)
  .Next(this.task_completion)
)

task_completion = (
  flow.View(views.TaskCompletion)
  .Permission('MOC.is_MOC_actor')
  .Assign(this.assign_actors)
  .Next(this.join_on_task_completion)
)
...
def assign_actors(self, activation):
  task = MOCTask.objects.filter(MOC=activation.process.MOC, assigned=False).first()
  task.assigned = True
  task.save()
  return User.objects.filter(email=task.assignee).first()
```

However, I can't put a `this` reference in the assign block, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users can be assigned inside `DynamicSplitActivation` when subsequent tasks are created

`def activate_next(self):
        if self._split_count:
            token_source = Token.split_token_source(
                 self.task.token, self.task.pk)
            for _ in range(self._split_count):
                activation = self.flow_task._next.activate(
                     prev_activation=self, token=next(token_source))
                activation.activate(..a user..)`

Comment: There is a typo instead of 'activation.activate(..a user..)' it should have read 'activation.assign(..a user..)'